# pybind11 variable return type

Tags: c++, pybind11

I have a C++ class which acts like a map that can contain different data types.

In C++, it is unknown at compile time what data type an entry is. Therefore, the programmer has to know and the accessor is templated:

```
auto a = map.get<int>("my-int-entry");
auto b = map.get<std::string>("my-string-entry");
```

At runtime, the map knows what type the entries have. So in python, I should be able to use the runtime type information.

```
a = map.get('my-int-entry') # a is of type int
b = map.get('my-string-entry') # b is of type string
```

I'd like that it looks up the type information at runtime, then calls `get<int>` if the runtime type is int, otherwise `get<std::string>`. Is there a way to do this directly in pybind11?
Or do I need another (pure python) function that calls the respectively mapped C++ functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would query your map in runtime about what type a key has, but this is the general idea of how I would do that:

```cpp
map_wrapper.def("get", [](Map& self, const std::string& key) -> py::object {
  if (self.is_a<int>(key)) {
    return py::cast(self.get<int>(key));
  } else if (self.is_a<std::string>(key)) {
    return py::cast(self.get<std::string>(key));
  } else if ...
});
```

You would need to know the types you want to support in advance.